# php strtotime 'third day of + 1 month' = false

Tags: php, strtotime

I want a loop like this:

This loop is OK:

```
while($d<=$d2) {  
        $x = "first day of + 1 month";
        $d=strtotime($x,$d);
        do_something($d);
}
```

But

```
while($d<=$d2) {  
        $x = "third day of + 1 month";
        $d=strtotime($x,$d);
        do_something($d);
}
```

doens't work: https://www.functions-online.com/strtotime.html gives "false"
How can I solve this?

(first, second, third etc is a variable)

Answer (score 1):

Without specifying a day of the week, only the first and last day work with "+ x  months". It only remains to work twice with strtotime. Example:

```
$d1= strtotime('first day of + 1 month',$d);
$day = 3;
$dateStr = date("Y-m-",$d1).sprintf("%02d",$day);
$d = strtotime($dateStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

best practice to add days in a date or day you can add any one sting on ($start_month_date_str) like DD/MM/YYYY or defined as words

```
$start_month_date_str = 'first day of December 2021';
$start_month_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_month_date_str));
$start_month_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_month_date . '+2  days'));
```